# CLGeocoder always fails on device but works in the simulator

Tags: ios, location, reverse-geocoding

I'm using CLGeocoder to reverse geocode the device's current location.  It works great on the Simulator, but always fails with an `kCLErrorNetwork` error on the device (iPhone 4 and iPad 3).

The code is very straightforward:

```
if ( geocoder == nil ) geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if ( error == nil ) {

        // Do good stuff with the placemark...

    } else {

        NSLog(@"unable to reverse geocode location %@ due to error: %@", self.location, error);
    }
}];
```

The error message printed is:

```
unable to reverse geocode location <[redacted],[redacted]> +/- 69.94m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/4/12 10:30:19 AM Eastern Daylight Time due to error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.
```

This method is only called once the CLLocationManager has provided a location, so the method is always passed a valid location.

I've tried it on several Wi-Fi networks and on the 3G network.  It never works on the device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should first check if placemarks==nil and if it is, then you are allowed to look at the error

Comment: @phix23 I'm afraid placemarks is nil, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the issue with your problem but I guess a network layer on the device crashed and meant it wasn't connected to the internet. Turning airplane mode off and on fixed the issue for me.